# View & Partial view Ajax submit position

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view & two partial views.I'm planning to use Ajax Submit `@using(Ajax.BeginForm`... and i will render two partial views to the view.

I wanted to know about my Ajax Form Submits should placed on View or Partial Views ? ( Because in one partial view that shows only a Grid no any form submit )

Comment: at the end of the day the final page rendering is what your concerned with..as long as the final rendering has well formed html your good to go most of the time. you can have multiple forms on a page just make sure that the html is well formed and the tags are nested correctly. Using html helpers can pose an issue without planning but just think though it...

Comment: The thing is i need to add some enty and also need to update my grid that is planning to put in partial view.

Comment: That's a whole other question...post your code and the error

Comment: No i just ask it before develop to get a idea about best way.